# Farewell to ymb1 (?)

Tags: discussion

It seems ymb1 has left us, for whatever reason it may be. It certainly is sad to lose such a significant contributor, I hope all is well.

Godspeed!

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61189751#61189751